# Edit xml file using xmldocument, search by attribute

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to write a small programme. With this programme i want to edit a xml file by searching for a specific attribute name. This attribute name appears many times in my xml file only the number is changing. I know i can do this by using linq or xmldocument there are many solutions. The code i wrote seems right to me, i dont understand whats wrong here. Can someone have a look at my code? I would be thankful for help.

All i want to edit is balance. Not more. Thats really all.

My xml file:

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?>
<Data>
<Place>
<Date Month="February">
  <Counter>2</Counter>
  <Player>1</Player>
  <Player>2</Player>
     <Game Name="Football">
       <IdNumber>1</IdNumber>
       <salutation>Mr</salutation>
       <prename>Prename1</prename>
       <surname>Surname1</surname>
       <maximumbalance>100</maximumbalance>
       <balance>100</balance>
    </Game>
    <Game Name="Tennis">
       <IdNumber>2</IdNumber>
       <salutation>Mr</salutation>
       <prename>Prename2</prename>
       <surname>Surname2</surname>
       <maximumbalance>100</maximumbalance>
       <balance>100</balance>
     </Game>
   </Date>
</Place>
</Data>
```

My Solution is here:

```
private void edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

{
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(Path);
XmlNode node = xdoc["Data"]["Place"]["Date"]["Game"]
int countvalues = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < countvalues; i++)

foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
{
if (childNode.Attributes["Name"].InnerText.Equals("Tennis"))
{
childNode["balance"].InnerText = xBal.Text;
}
}
xdoc.Save(Path);

}
```

There are many more entries in my xml file (Tennis1, Tennis2 and so on ) thats not the problem right now,

the line: childNode.Attributes["Name"].InnerText.Equals("Tennis")) is null, dont know why

... i am using Visual studio 2015 and WPF

regards
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. Your main node already contains element Game - that's why you won't be able to find it in ChildNode. I corrected your main path not to include Game node. So now, you can find it in ChildNodes collection. I added some checks for Node.Name and Attribute name to be sure that it is Game node. It should work for you.

```
XmlNode node = xdoc["Data"]["Place"]["Date"];
int countvalues = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < countvalues; i++)
{
    foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (childNode.Name == "Game" && childNode.Attributes["Name"].InnerText.Equals("Tennis"))
        {
            childNode["balance"].InnerText = xBal.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't exactly match the structure of your Xml document.  You left out the Player element.  Try XmlNode node = xdoc["Data"]["Place"]["Date"]["Player"]["Game"]

Comment: Player is on the same level as Game. So this is not a problem and it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this example. 
I think it will work properly.

```
        string xBal = "200";
        string path = "D:\\xml.xml";

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(path);
        XmlNodeList NodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Game");

        foreach (XmlNode item in NodeList)
        {
            if (item.Attributes[0].InnerText.Equals("Tennis"))
            {
                XmlNode balance = item.SelectSingleNode("balance");

                balance.InnerText = xBal;
            }
        }

        xmlDoc.Save(path);
```

Comment: This solutions works fine, thanks a lot. But all solutions here are good

Comment: I'm glad to help.